# Prevent scapy from network is down

Tags: python, linux, scapy

I'm running a sniffing script on raspberry pi using scapy. Is there anyway that I can keep scapy running when network is down ? Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfz02.png)

Comment: Ofcourse, not if you are making internet requests

Comment: Why don't you try | except, continue  when making calls, I'm not entirely familiar with scrapy, but it will raise an exception for sure, as that's how its supposed to be. When I work with requests library, I make sure to create try excepts for the requests, for the different supposed exceptions it might throw, and let it crash on unseen exceptions. Put the code raising the error here and I will try to help you.